# Portable/POSIX way of getting range of arguments in shell script without shift

Tags: shell-script, posix

I thought I had found a portable or POSIX-compatible way of getting ranges of arguments in shell scripts, but I've forgotten it and I can't seem to find it again. I think its syntax looked like `${@:1}` or `${@:1:3}` in `bash`. This method:

- Could get all the arguments after nth argument.
- A range of arguments starting from the nth argument up to the either the mth or was given the length of the range to get.
- Did not use `shift`.
- Did not use `eval`.
- Did not use `$*`.
- Handled arguments with no restrictions on what characters, excepting `\x00`, were in them.

What could it have been? In the event that I might not have actually seen the method that I thought I saw, is there a way of getting ranges of arguments passed to a acript or a function that is portable/POSIX-compatible and meets the above requirements?

Comment: Ubuntu people [suggest using awk](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.24.7Bfoo:3.5B:1.5D.7D)

Answer (score 0):

If AWKing, is this (sorry if I don't get your question well)?

```bsh
awk '
  BEGIN{
    first=3;
    last=7;
    for(i=3;i<=7;i++)
      print ARGV[i];
  }
' ${@:+"$@"}
```